# In 16.04 usb-creator-gtk how can I use vfat instead of iso9660?

Tags: usb, filesystem, live-usb

I created a bootable pendrive using usb-creator-gtk
On my current 14.04 the pendrive always ended up with a writeable filesystem, but the new one was created with iso9660.

I want to wirte/modify the contents. how do I do that?

[edit]
Option to create some persistence on the USB was also not available.

Comment: I used unetbootin, but still - why break features on good old usb-creator?